# UNIX permissions on directory

Tags: unix, directory, user-permissions

What command should i use for the below scenario.

user 1 owns a folder in the shared folder nfs mount on host 1. If I need to change the owner of the folder to user 2 in host 2 which has access to the shared folder. How can I do it?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Use the "chown" command.

Example:

```
chown user2 folder # Change the owner of folder to user2
```